# How to find out which of the games happened on Mondays only?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have tried 2 codes, the first one hasn't worked, while the second has. I basically have to display how many games were played on Mondays and show the teams that played them.

```
MATCH (t:Teams)
WHERE date({year:2019, month: 1 }) > t.Date <= date({year:2018, month:12})
RETURN t.HomeTeam AS HomeTeam,
    t.AwayTeam AS AwayTeam,
    t.Date AS Date
```

The result is: (No changes, no records) - nothing

```
MATCH (t:Teams)
WITH [item in split(t.Date, "/") | toInteger(item)] AS dateComponents
WITH ({day: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1], year: dateComponents[2]}).dayOfWeek AS date
WHERE date = 1
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

The result is: Count(*) 0

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a couple of things going on in your first query. The date matching line

```
WHERE date({year:2019, month: 1 }) > t.Date <= date({year:2018, month:12})
```

is looking for a date that is less than 20190101 and less than or equal to 20181201. If you are actually looking for a date between those two values you need to change the operator to greather than equals for 201801.

That said, if `Date` is actually a string then the date comparison will not work either.

In your second query, it looks like you decided that Date was indeed a string and you split it up but still did not get any results. Although you break the date string up into its components you did not supply the `date()` function around your date components in this line...

```
WITH ({day: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1], year: dateComponents[2]}).dayOfWeek AS date
```

Try this for your second query.

```
MATCH (t:Teams)
WITH [item in split(t.Date, "/") | toInteger(item)] AS dateComponents
WITH date({day: dateComponents[0], month: dateComponents[1], year: dateComponents[2]}).dayOfWeek AS date
WHERE date = 1
RETURN COUNT(*)
```